# argc and argv[] in C language

Tags: c

I'm learning C and in one of the examples we write a program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// go through each string in argv

int i = 0;
while(i < argc)
{
    printf("arg %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    i++;
}

// let's make our own array of stringd
char *states[] = {"California", "Oregon", "Washington", "Texas"};

int num_states = 4;
i = 0; // watch for this
while(i < num_states) 
{
    printf("state %d: %s\n", i, states[i]);
    i++;
}

return 0;
}
```

and if I run it in terminal like this:

```
./ex11 test arguments
```

I get an output of:

```
arg 0: ./ex11
arg 1: test
arg 2: arguments
state 0: California
state 1: Oregon
state 2: Washington
state 3: Texas
```

However I don't understand why the "Test argument" part gets printed, i know it has something to do with `argc` and `argv` but I don't know how.

Can someone explain this to me (preferably in a simple manner)?

Comment: Please consult your local C language reference - preferably, a book. This is very, very basic stuff.

Comment: "I wrote a loop which prints out arguments. So why does my program print its arguments?" ----- I don't even...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a command, any command, is run by the shell (actually, any shell) on Unix, then the command line is converted into an array of strings:

```
cmd_argv[0] = "./ex11";
cmd_argv[1] = "test";
cmd_argv[2] = "arguments";
cmd_argv[3] = NULL;
cmd_argc    = 3;
```

and then invokes:

```
execvp(cmd_argv[0], cmd_argv);
```

Note that all I/O redirections are removed, etc.  Internally, the system ends up counting the number of non-null pointers at the start of the `cmd_argv` array and passes them as `argv` in the new program, and the count as `argc`.  The new program is guaranteed that `argc >= 0` and `argv[argc] == NULL`.

This list is almost the same form as the list of states; the primary difference is that `cmd_argv[cmd_argc]` is a null pointer, which is certainly not guaranteed with the states data.

Answer (score 1):

That's what your first loop does, it iterates through the strings in argv (which contains the name of the program and the arguments you typed after it), and prints them out. Argc is the number of arguments you passed, or equivalently the length of argv.

Answer (score 1):

argv is the command line arguments, including the executable's name (aguments' values). argc is the amount of elements in argv (argument count).

In your first loop, you are printing the contents of argv, therefore you get the arguments that were passed to your program.